# Delete a part of a file?

Tags: c++

I have want to code a program that functions to open a file and if I find "Hello World", the program will automatically copy the text before "Hello World" in to a new file.

The problem is, how could I delete the text 'hello world' in the 'buffer', for example :

```
  buffer = new char [Size];

  ifstream fstr;

  fstr.open(path, ios::in);

  fstr.read(buffer, (Size));

  fstr.close();

  //what should i write here about copying the rest of the text except 

  //Hello World? 

  ofstream outputFile(path2, ios::out);

  outputFile << buffer;

  outputFile.close();
```

Thank you for helping me :) Btw I'm using Borland C++ and I'm a learner.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is all text you could use [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) to find "Hello World" and then set the end of the string.

```
char *Found = strstr(buffer, "Hello World"); 
if (Found != NULL) 
   *Found = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

First some gotcha! type issues.

1. What if the file doesn't contain "Hello World"?
2. What if it contains "Hello       World"?
3. What if it contains "Hello World", but the "World" starts on the next line?

I don't have the answer to these. That's up to you, and your instructor if this is homework.

Now a suggestion: Use C++ strings (std::string) rather than C-style strings.

In C you could call `strstr` to find the location of that string. If found, either write a 0 at the found location, or `strcpy` the empty string to the found location.

In C++ you can find the location of the target string with the member function `find`. If found, erase the stuff at and after the found location with the member function `erase`.

Which function / member names makes more sense? Which method of erasing from "Hello World" on makes more sense? Which code would you rather come back to six months from now?